# Return partial object in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I would like to return a partial object in a response for another object type.

For example, I have a UserProfile model:

```
  var id: Int?
  var email: String
  var firstName: String?
  var lastName: String?
```

and an Adult model:

```
  var id: Int?
  var nickname: String
  var type: String
  var user: User.UserProfile
  var family: Family
```

Say I would like to return just the UserProfile's email address in the Adult response, what is the way to go about that?

I have tried an approach with child/parent relationships, where my Adult model is more like:

```
  var id: Int?
  var nickname: String
  var type: String
  var user: User.ID
  var family: Family
```

..but then my response just contains an object ID, but I really want to return a partial (or even full in some cases) object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is done is to create a 'public' definition of your model, which will represent the JSON you return from your route.

For your model, you might create a struct like this:

```
struct AdultResponse: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var nickname: String
    var type: String
    var email: String
    var family: Family

    init(adult: Adult) {
        self.id = adult.id
        self.nickname = adult.nickname
        self.type = adult.type
        self.email = adult.user.email
        self.family = adult.family
    }
}
```

You can then get your `Adult` model from the database, create an `AdultResponse` and return that from your route.

Comment: Thanks. However whenever I declare a struct with a property of type `Family` for example, I get back the error "operator does not exist: jsonb = bigint" in the response.

Comment: @nickjf89 Hmm, not really sure what would cause that. Maybe someone on the [Discord chat](https://discord.gg/vapor) could help.